# Many-To-Many select only rows with exactly same tags

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have 3 tables: tags, products and relation table between them.
Relation table looks for example like this:

```
tagId | ProductId
  1   |    1
  2   |    1
  2   |    9
```

The user can pick two options "**All of these**" or "**One of these**".

So if user picks **All of these**, it's means that the product must have exactly all of tags which the user chose.

So if user pick tags with id **1** and **2**, it should select only product with id **1**, because this product **has exactly the same tags** the user chose. (Another way is if the user picks the tag with id **2**, it should select only product with id **9**.)

So, the product has to have all tags which the user chose (no more, no less).

SQL that I already have for Any/One of these:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.SKU 
FROM SKUToEAN as s 
LEFT JOIN ProductDetails as p ON s.ProductDetailID=p.id 
JOIN ProductTagRelation as ptr ON (ptr.productId=p.id and ptr.tagId IN(Ids of selected tags))
```

Example behavior:

```
TagId = 1 it should select => None
TagId = 2 it should select => 9
TagId = 1,2 it should select = 1,9
```

So probably I need two queries. One for any/one of these ( I already have this one ) and the second for all of these.
With PHP I decide which query to use.

Comment: You said "not more, not less".  When you search for 1,2, expected result is not 1?  9 only has tag 2 (missing tag 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY` on the `ProductID` and use conditional aggregation based filtering inside the `Having` clause. MySQL automatically casts boolean values to 0/1 when using in numeric context. So, in order to have a specific `tagID` value available against a `ProductID`, its `SUM(tagId = ..)` should be **1**.

**All of these:**

```
SELECT ptr.productId, s.SKU 
FROM SKUToEAN AS s 
LEFT JOIN ProductDetails AS p 
  ON p.id = s.ProductDetailID 
JOIN ProductTagRelation AS ptr 
  ON ptr.productId = p.id 
GROUP BY ptr.productId, s.SKU 
HAVING SUM(ptr.tagID = 1) AND -- 1 should be there
       SUM(ptr.tagID = 2) AND -- 2 should be there
       NOT SUM(ptr.tagID NOT IN (1,2)) -- other than 1,2 should not be there
```

Comment: @FrederikFako please edit the question and add this there. I will modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: @FrederikFako please note that queries will be different for the two cases.

Comment: Im using PHP if clause to decide which querie use. Im sorry for my English, I hope I understood what you mean

Comment: Jep, i think this is what I need. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are looking for (for all condition)?

```
select product.id
from products
inner join <table> on products.id = <table>.productId
group by product.id
having group_concat(<table>.tagId order by <table>.tagId separator ',') = '1,2';
```

Comment: I edited my question can you look at it now? 
I only want Exaclly All of these. Any/One of these I already has.

Comment: This should do the tricks.  If you search 1 and 2, search = `'1,2'`;